# WCF REST Webinvoke

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Сервис

```
[ServiceContract]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
    public class CustomConfigurationService
    {

        /*[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]*/
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, 
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
        [OperationContract]
        public string GetTransformValue(string name)
        {
            return "<order>" + name + "</order>";
        }
    }
```

Клиент

```
if (!IsAuthentificated)
            {
                return "";
            }
            string requestString = string.Format("http://crmtest.unistroyrf.ru/0/rest/CustomConfigurationService/GetTransformValue" +
                "?name={0}", param);
            HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(requestString) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.CookieContainer = AuthCookie;
            using (var response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.Default);

                Console.WriteLine("Response stream received.");
                Console.WriteLine(readStream.ReadToEnd());
                Console.ReadKey();
                response.Close();
                readStream.Close();
            }
```

Выводит почему-то такое (смотреть скриншот)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
<order>12345</order>
Можно как-то корректно вернуть xml?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Возвращайте не `string`, а `XElement`:

```
[OperationContract]
public XElement GetTransformValue(string name)
{
    return new XElement("order", name);
}
```

Comment: А если нужно вернуть полноценный XML что нужно возвращать?

Comment: @user197357 А чем вам `XElement` не полноценный XML?

Comment: Мне удобней этим работать с XML
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;

var sw = new StringWriter();
var xw = XmlWriter.Create(sw, settings);
xw.WriteStartDocument();
xw.WriteStartElement("Order");

xw.WriteAttributeString("Id", name);

xw.WriteEndElement();
xw.WriteEndDocument();
xw.Close();

sw.ToString();

И в итоге он всё равно строку возвращать должен.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам удобнее работать с XmlWriter - значит, тут что-то не так. Тем не менее, XLinq предоставляет и такой интерфейс:

```
[OperationContract]
public XElement GetTransformValue(string name)
{
    var doc = new XDocument();
    using (var w = doc.CreateWriter()) {
      w.WriteStartElement("Order");
      w.WriteAttributeString("Id", name);
      w.WriteEndElement(); 
    }
    return doc.Root;
}
```